# Devise not updating anything but password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Using `Devise 3.2.4` and `Rails 4.1.1`, I'm having trouble making `Devise` update anything user-related besides the `email` and `password`.

I have the following included in my `edit.html.erb` (in addition to the defaults):

```
<%= f.collection_select :plan_id, Plan.all, :id, :name if current_user.admin? %>
```

and the following in my `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_paramaters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  # let devise accept more paramaters
  def configure_permitted_paramaters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
        :plan_id, :current_password)
    end

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :employee_number,
        :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
end
```

and yet, when I submit the form, I get the right parameters (including the changed `plan_id`):

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Token",
"user"=>{"email"=>"taylor@taylorskidmore.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "plan_id"=>"5"},
"commit"=>"Update"}
```

But nothing in the actual database changes besides the new password. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the entire server log of the put:

```
Started PUT "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-11 11:30:09 -0400
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Token", "user"=>
{"email"=>"taylor@taylorskidmore.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>
"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "plan_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 2  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
Division Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `divisions`.* FROM `divisions`  WHERE `divisions`.`name` = 'Sample Name' LIMIT 1
Plan Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `plans`.* FROM `plans`  WHERE `plans`.`company` = 'company 1' AND   `plans`.`shortname` = 'plan 1' LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 106ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

my `user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validate :user_is_eligible
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :division

  def is_eligible?
    db = Sequel.connect('mysql2://localhost')
    eligible_users = db[:eligible_users]
    user = eligible_users.where(:first_name => self.first_name, :last_name => self.last_name,
                                :employee_number => self.employee_number)[:id]
    if user.present?
      @division = Division.find_by_name(user[:division])
      self.division_id = @division.id
      self.plan_id = Plan.find_by_company_and_shortname(@division.company, user[:plan].downcase).id
    end

    user.present?
  end

  private
  def user_is_eligible
    errors.add(:base, "Check Employee Information and Try Again") unless self.is_eligible?
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you add a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController` as `before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?` ?

Comment: @KirtiThorat `before_action`, but yes.

Comment: Can you share the complete code of `ApplicationController`. Update it in the question.

Comment: Also it would be great, if you could share the full server log generated upon edit form submission.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55444/discussion-between-kirti-thorat-and-taylor-skidmore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a validation in the `User` model, where you are resetting the `plan_id` which is why the `plan_id` that you are passing from form is not getting updated in the database.

As per the chat discussion, you simply need the validation while creating the user record so what you can do is pass an option `on: :create` for the validation as below so that the validation would not be executed while updating an existing user record.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #..    
  validate :user_is_eligible, on: :create ## Updated this line
  ## ...
end
```